# Getting default (not CI) 404 for all pages

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to develop using CI for the first time.  I have not changed any defaults WRT paths, .htaccess, etc.  Two hours ago I was able to load pages; now I am not.  All of this is on a virtual box running on my Mac, and I had been messing with the virtualbox settings in order to try to get the web pages to load while connected to a VPN (did not succeed).  At no time did I edit any files on the VM, whether for connect settings or related to CI and my project.

Giving up with the VPN, I returned to my project to continue with code enhancements.  Only now, as my title suggests, nothing will load.  The default "It works" page loads so I know nginx is responding to requests.  I don't get the Code Igniter 404 page -- I get the generic:

Not Found

The requested URL /index.php/c_login/ was not found on this server.

In this example, c_login extends CI_Controller and displays a view in its index function.

Based on my searches:

- My config.php contains $config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
- There was no .htaccess file previously, and that is still the case
- I don't understand the bit about capital first letter in my controllers, as I've had lower case since I started the project and had no problem
- Except for a minor change to a view file (not trying to load that one right now), nothing has changed since the last pull from the git server

I had left the welcome_message view and welcome controller in place when starting this project, and that no longer works either.  Any ideas?  I am at a complete loss.

Comment: This appears to be a port forwarding issue, as when I use port 8000 I'm able to pull up all of my pages.  Thanks for the comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

In your `config.php`

1. `$config['base_url']    = '';`
2. `$config['index_page'] = '';`
3. `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

then in `.htaccess`(this should be place out side of application folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT 01**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and restarted nginx but the problem is the same.